# Kubernetes, extract a certificate from a configmap to a file

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I need to extract the ca-bundle.crt from the configmap "kubelet-serving-ca" in the namespace "openshift-kube-apiserver" to use it on another configmap and on a pod using the path to the file.

how I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: `kubectl get cm -n openshift-kube-apiserver kubelet-serving-ca  -o jsonpath='{.data.ca-bundle\.crt}' >  ca-bundle.crt` hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to extract `ca-bundle.crt` from the config map `kubelet-serving-ca` in the namespace `openshift-kube-apiserver` and use it in another configmap, please use the following commands which was provided by “P….” in the comments section.

```
kubectl get configmap -n openshift-kube-apiserver kubelet-serving-ca  
-o jsonpath='{.data.ca-bundle\.crt}' >  ca-bundle.crt
```

If the fields by the jsonpath expression needs to be printed into another file then please use the below command along with the kubectl command.

```
-o jsonpath-file=<filename>
```

The syntax `kubectl get configmap` retrieves the value of a key from the specified file and the syntax `-o jsonpath=<template>`  prints the fields defined in a jsonpath expression.

Please refer to the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/) for more information.